# Given a function f that is continious, differentiable. Show that there is a c in the interval so that f'(c)=1.

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question regarding an exam question that I just had.

There was a function f: [0,2]$\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that was continious on [0,2], differentiable on (0,2). Besides that f(0)=f(1)=0 and f(2)=1.

So now I had to show that there excisted a c$_1 \in$(1,2) so that f'(c$_1$)=1. 
My first thought was to use the mean value theorem, and filling in all the numbers given.

$f'(c)= \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = \frac{f(2)-f(1)}{2-1} = \frac{1-0}{1-0} =1.$

That does give me the answer that I was looking for! But is it the correct way to answer such a question? 
I was really sure my answer was correct untill I started the other question to show that there was a c$_2 \in$ (0,2) so that f'(c$_2$)= 1/3. And I couldnt make much of that question.

Was it correct for me to use the mean value theorem? 
If I have to retake the real analysis exam again I really want to know how to answer this!

Sorry if my title wasnt that clear! And thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with the mean value theorem is absolutely the correct way to answer the question.

The second question is a bit harder. Since $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, there exists a point $c_1 \in (0,1)$ satisfying $f'(c_1) = 0$. Since $f(1) = 0$ and $f(2) = 1$, there exists a point $c_2 \in (1,2)$ satisfying $f'(c_2) = \dfrac{f(2) - f(1)}{2 - 1} = 1$. Now apply the Darboux theorem (the intermediate value theorem for derivatives): since $f'(c_1) = 0$ and $f'(c_2) = 1$, $c_1 < c_2$, and $0 < \frac 13 < 1$, there exists a point $c_3 \in (c_1,c_2)$ satisfying $f'(c_3) = \frac 13$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand it now